# Prevent unnecessary event from Kivy Properties

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Kivy in an application where several widgets are used to modify/edit a set of data (the model). When some data is changed in one widget others need to be informed that something has changed so they can update their view.
To do this I use Kivy Properties to mirror the model data, and this works fine.

However the first time the Kivy Properties are set, when reading in the model data, this generates alot of unnecessary updates in the UI. I would like there to be a way to update a Kivy Property without generating update events.
I have looked in the documentation (https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html) and in the code (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx) but I have not been able to find anything to do this.

How can this be solved?
I have done a very simple example app to show how the code is organized and where the problem occurs.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

model_data = ["Data1","Data2","Data3"]

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        tl = TestLayout()
        tl.read_data(model_data)
        return tl

class TestLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.test_list = TestList()
        self.test_edit = TestEdit()
        self.add_widget(self.test_list)
        self.add_widget(self.test_edit)

        self.test_list.adapter = ListAdapter(data=[],
                                             cls=ListItemButton,
                                             selection_mode='single')
        self.test_list.adapter.bind(selection=self.select_data)
        self.test_edit.bind(data=self.update_list)

    def read_data(self, data_list):
        self.test_list.init_list(data_list)

    def select_data(self, list_adapter, selection):
        if len(selection) > 0:
            data =  selection[0].text
            self.test_edit.init_data(data)

    def update_list(self, test_edit, data):
        self.test_list.adapter.selection[0].text = data


class TestList(ListView):
    def init_list(self, data_list):
        self.adapter.data = [str(data) for data in data_list]

class TestEdit(BoxLayout):
    data = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.text_input=TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.text_input)
        btn_update = Button(text="Update data")
        self.add_widget(btn_update)

        btn_update.bind(on_press=self.update_data)

    def init_data(self, data):
        # Setting the data property the first time triggers an unnecessary update.
        # How can this be prevented?
        self.data = data 
        self.text_input.text = data

    def update_data(self, btn):
        self.data = self.text_input.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp()
    app.run()
```

Also as you can see in the example code, an unnecessary update is dispatch whenever you select a new item in the list view.

Have I overlooked something obvious? Or is this not supported by Kivy?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to update a property without triggering update events. I guess we could add this, but I'm also not clear why it's an issue - if you don't want the events to do anything, why not just ignore them?

Comment: @inclement It is not a big issue really. It just annoys me that the gui is updating when it's not needed. And it is not possible to ignore the events, since the receiver cannot know if the event was triggered due to something has really changed or if it was just the property that was initialized. See my code example to see what I mean. The workaround I have at the moment is to have a flag in the property value where the sender of the event can signal if this event can be skipped.